# How to insert mult array values in db using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to insert data in DB with three entries. But only one row insert in DB with this code.

```php
$parent_id = $object->id;
$amounts = $request->amount;
$payess = $request->add_payee;
dd($amounts,$payess);
foreach ($payess as $key => $ids) {
    App\Payees_amount::create([
        'add_payee' => $ids[$key],
        'building_id' => $parent_id,
        'payee_amount' => $amounts[$key],
    ]);
}
```

This arrays I want in DB against one id :

[image]

Comment: Where do these data come from? a form that a user fills in?

Answer (score 0):

use array_map with array_combine :

```
$parent_id = $object->id;
$amounts = $request->amount;
$payess = $request->add_payee;

$res = array_map(null, $payess , $amounts );
$keys = array("pay", "amount");
$res = array_map(function ($e) use ($keys) {return array_combine($keys, $e);}, $res);

foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    App\Payees_amount::create([
        'add_payee' => $value['pay'],
        'building_id' => $parent_id,
        'payee_amount' => $value['amount'],
    ]);
}
```